# Invoking windows batch file from Linux

Tags: windows, linux

I have an application running only on Windows and a batch file that launches it.
I want to invoke this batch file from Linux, meaning something like Linux batch will launch the windows batch with parameters and this in its turn run my application.

Can I do that? How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could install an ssh server in the windows box (Cygwin has one), then from linux do something like:

```
ssh user@windows-box c:/path/to/batch.cmd
```

and that should launch your application in the windows box.

Comment: This worked for me, but the path was relative and followed linux syntax, i.e. `ssh user@windows-box /batch.bat`

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is probably to install an ssh server on the windows box.  [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) includes an ssh server.

Depending on how precise your timing needs are, you might be able to have an "at" job on the windows box that runs periodically (every 5 minutes?) and runs if it sees that a particular file exists, deleting the file.  Then you could use [Samba](http://www.samba.org/)/smbclient to create the file.  You would need to turn on filesharing on the windows box for this to work.

If the windows box has a web server, you could write a [CGI](http://www.w3.org/CGI/), and trigger it using [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Answer (score 0):

Our build process currently goes the other way: a windows sever kicks off things on the Linux server using plink (part of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)). You might be able to set something similar up.

Answer (score 0):

This may cause a security issue. Our information security person did not allow me to invoke any programs directly.

The safer way is to set up server on Windows computer. This can be a web-server for example. And then invoke your process inside PHP/Perl/Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) that allows you to execute windows commands/batch scripts without running ssh server.