# How to run a windows bat file from unix script

Tags: shell, unix

Could you help me run the windows bat file from unix script

```
ftp_data()
```

{
ftp wsapp00012.srv.dir.abc.com << EOF
prompt off
asci
cd photo
cmd  Photo_load.bat
quit
EOF
}

ftp_data

Answer (score 0):

a .bat file is specifically a windows scripting file that usually calls windows applications within the .bat file. You should be able to open the bat file in any text editor and see what applications it calls to but you won't be able to run that on a Linux machine.
There is a slight chance that you could get the game to run using WINE, http://www.winehq.org/ but a game that uses batch files like that I would say you have a very slim chance.

Comment: Thanks can we run windows jar file from unix script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238013/invoking-windows-batch-file-from-linux -- you can also check this link too usefull

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable hope this is enough to do what you asked